# EmailComposer plugin for windows 8 phone phonegap

Tags: windows-8, phonegap-plugins

I am developing phonegap project for windows 8 phone and I want to implement phonegap emailComposer plugin found on github : https://github.com/stanislavfeldman/phonegap-plugins/commit/686465b1659e9a0736a047fd2322704ac7694064

I am getting this error - **The type or namespace name 'JSON' does not exist in the namespace 'WP7CordovaClassLib.Cordova' (are you missing an assembly reference?)** in EmailComposer.cs file.

I am using cordova 2.6.0 version. Is this cordova version issues?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't fixed the emailComposer plugin issues but found "mailto" and it worked fine on windows 8 phone.

Sample code is:

var sMailTo = "mailto:";
sMailTo += escape(toRecipient) +"?subject=" +escape(subject) +"&body=" +escape(body) +"&cc=" +escape(ccRecipient) +"&bcc=" +escape(bccRecipient);
window.open(sMailTo, '_self');

I don't think it is a good solution. Can anyone please suggest me the better solution?

Answer (score 0):

hello please check below link regarding namespace

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_plugin-development_windows-phone_index.md.html

Comment: Link only answers are not answers, but comments.